# SQL server queries in fitnesse

Tags: sql-server, fitnesse, dbfit

How to execute Sql Server Scripts(queries) in Fitnesse

I know that there is a plugin called DBfit but its java version does not support sql server

Please help me in executing sql server queries

Also how can i execute a exe file using fitnesse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET version of DBFit supports SqlServer.

http://fitsharp.github.com

Comment: i know that but i m using java version of fitnesse and all my fitnesse pages are in java version

Comment: You can have both Java and .NET tests in the same FitNesse wiki - although I understand why you'd like to keep to one platform.

Answer (score 0):

DbFit does support SQL Server.